# why tesseract 3.0 does not recognize text inside box/rectangles/squares?

Tags: java, image-processing, ocr, tesseract

[image]

I'have tried tesseract on this image and some scanned images with some text inside rectangles.
but it fails each time with "empty image" as output. please suggest me how can i solve this problem as I'm working on form prosessing. plz do help

Comment: Is all text skewed like that?

Comment: no i first deskewed the image and then aplied tesseract

Comment: Did you try doing it without skewing?

Comment: I think that it might be the case that tesseract is *thinking* that the border is part of the text. Could you try and test it out without any borders?

Comment: its working fine without border. so how can i make this border disappear or neglect by tesseract ??

Comment: You should do some form of edge detection and discard the stronger ones. Or, a harder approach would be to detect regions that appear to be text and discard everything else. If you post some actual examples I could try to help.

Comment: thank you for considering me .i attached actual image when i input it to tesseract it shows some garbage text and without boxes/rectangles tesseract gives perfect output text. plz help me to get rid of this problem.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do would be to draw a section of the image you are getting, where the section would be the inner part of the border. You could find a tutorial [here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0280__SWT/DrawpartofanImage.htm).