# Why can't tesseract-ocr detect text which is in a box?

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

Consider this experiment:

I have two images, one with free text and another with text with-in a box (surrounded by border)

If I run tesseract-ocr on these two images, the free text image outputs 'Text' while the boxed image outputs Nothing ''

Why is that?

As a fix, I can crop borders using some image processing but I am trying to know what's causing this problem.

[free image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VCafL.png)
[Boxed image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SnBFt.png)

So far,
I cropped borders of the image using below logic [We should feed it outer border contour-cropped image] and I then I was able to detect the text. However I don't understand why tesseract isn't detecting the boxed text. Feel free to experiment on attached images.

```
`# Below code modified (x,y) and (height,width) `
`# in a way that new values choose a smaller box enclosed`
`# by the original box`

 y = y + int(0.025*h) 
 x = x + int(0.025*w)
 h = h - int(0.05*h)
 w = w - int(0.05*w)
```

Comment: Please share what you have tried so far

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13678950/why-tesseract-3-0-does-not-recognize-text-inside-box-rectangles-squares


y = y + int(0.025*h)
x = x + int(0.025*w)
h = h - int(0.05*h)
w = w - int(0.05*w)

I cropped borders of the image using above logic and I then I was able to detect the text. However I don't understand why tesseract isn't detecting the boxed text. Feel free to experiment on attached images.